# Clarification on changes made outside of Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I don't fully understand how Terraform handles external changes. Let's take an example:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2-test" {
  ami           = "ami-0d71ea30463e0ff8d"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

### 1: security group modification

The default security group has been manually replaced by another one. Terraform detects the change:

```
❯ terraform plan --refresh-only
aws_instance.ec2-test: Refreshing state... [id=i-5297abcc6001ce9a8]

Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform

Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the last "terraform apply" which may have affected this plan:

  # aws_instance.ec2-test has changed
  ~ resource "aws_instance" "ec2-test" {
        id                                   = "i-5297abcc6001ce9a8"
      ~ security_groups                      = [
          - "default",
          + "test",
        ]
        tags                                 = {}
      ~ vpc_security_group_ids               = [
          + "sg-8231be9a95a4b1886",
          - "sg-f2fc3af19c4adefe0",
        ]
        # (28 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (7 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }
```

No change planned:

```
❯ terraform plan
aws_instance.ec2-test: Refreshing state... [id=i-5297abcc6001ce9a8]

No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration and found no differences, so no changes are needed.
```

It seems normal as we did not set the `security_groups` argument in the `resource` block (the desired state is aligned with the current state).

### 2: IAM instance profile added

An IAM role has been manually attached to the instance. Terraform also detects the change:

```
❯ terraform plan --refresh-only
aws_instance.ec2-test: Refreshing state... [id=i-5297abcc6001ce9a8]

Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform

Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the last "terraform apply" which may have affected this plan:

  # aws_instance.ec2-test has changed
  ~ resource "aws_instance" "ec2-test" {
      + iam_instance_profile                 = "test"
        id                                   = "i-5297abcc6001ce9a8"
        tags                                 = {}
        # (30 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (7 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }


This is a refresh-only plan, so Terraform will not take any actions to undo these. If you were expecting these changes then you can apply this plan to record the updated values in the Terraform state without
changing any remote objects.
```

However, Terraform also plans to revert the change:

```
❯ terraform plan
aws_instance.ec2-test: Refreshing state... [id=i-5297abcc6001ce9a8]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_instance.ec2-test will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_instance" "ec2-test" {
      - iam_instance_profile                 = "test" -> null
        id                                   = "i-5297abcc6001ce9a8"
        tags                                 = {}
        # (30 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (7 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

I tried to figure out why these two changes don't produce the same effect. This article highlights differences depending on the argument default values: https://nedinthecloud.com/2021/12/23/terraform-apply-when-external-change-happens/

But the `security_groups` and `iam_instance_profile` arguments seems similar (optional with no default value), so why Terraform is handling these two cases differently?

(tested with Terraform v1.2.2, hashicorp/aws 4.21.0)

Comment: This is a really interesting question. I think the Wordpress article hints at the answer. My guess is that `iam_instance_profile` has a default value of `null` while there is no default value for security groups. I bet they just haven't updated the documentation to reflect the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handling of these situations unfortunately depends a lot on decisions made by the provider developer, since it's the provider's responsibility to decide how to reconcile any differences between the configuration and the prior state. (The "prior state" is what Terraform calls the state that results from running the "refresh" steps to synchronize with the remote system).

Terraform Core takes the values you've defined in the configuration (if any optional arguments are unset, Terraform Core uses `null` to represent that) and the values from the prior state and sends both of them to the provider to implement the planning step. The provider can then do whatever logic it wants as long as the planned new value for each attribute is consistent with the input. "Consistent" means that one of the following conditions is true:

1. The planned value is equal to the value set in the configuration.

   This is the most straightforward situation to follow, but there are various reasons why a provider might not do this, which I'll discuss later.
2. The planned value is equal to the value stored in the prior state.

   This represents situations where the value in the prior state is *functionally equivalent* to the value in the configuration but not exactly equal, such as if the remote system treats a particular string as case insensitive and the two values differ only in case.
3. The provider indicated in its schema that this is a value that can be decided by the remote system, such as an object ID that's generated by the remote system during the apply step, and the corresponding value in the configuration was `null` to represent the argument not being set at all.

   In this case the provider gets to choose whichever value it wants, because the configuration says nothing about the attribute and thus the remote system has authority on what the value is.

From what you've described, it sounds like in your first example the provider used approach number 3, while in the second example the provider used approach number 1.

Since I am not the developer of this provider I cannot say for certain why the developers made the decisions they did here, but one common reason why a provider developer might choose option three is for situations where a particular value can potentially be set by multiple different resource types, in which case the provider might be designed to treat an absent argument in the configuration as meaning "keep whatever the remote system already has", whereas a non-null argument in the configuration would mean "set the remote system to use this given value".

For `iam_instance_profile` it seems like the provider considers `null` to be a valid configuration value for that argument and uses it to represent the EC2 instance having no associated instance profile at all. For `vpc_security_groups` and `security_groups` though, leaving the argument set to `null` in the configuration (or omitting it, which is equivalent) the provider treats that as "keep whatever the remote system has", and so Terraform just acknowledges the change but doesn't propose to undo it.

Based on my knowledge about EC2, I can guess that the reason here is probably that the underlying EC2 API has two different ways to set security groups: you can either use the legacy EC2-Classic style of specifying a security group by name (the `security_groups` argument in the provider), or the new EC2-VPC style of specifying it by ID (the `vpc_security_group_ids` argument in the provider). Whichever of the two you choose, the remote system will presumably populate the other one automatically and therefore without this special exception in the provider it would be impossible for any configuration to converge unless you set both `security_groups` *and* `vpc_security_group_ids` and set them to both refer to the same security groups. To avoid that, I think the provider just lets whichever one of the two you left unset automatically track the remote system, which has the side-effect the provider cannot automatically "fix" changes made outside of Terraform unless you set at least one of them so the provider can see what the correct value ought to be.

Terraform's ability to reconcile changes in the remote system by resetting back to match the configuration is a "best effort" mechanism because in many cases that requirement comes into conflict with other requirements, and provider developers must therefore decide on a case-by-case basis what to prioritize. Although Terraform does try its best to tell you about changes outside of Terraform and to propose fixing them where possible, the only certain way to keep your Terraform configuration and your remote system synchronized is to prevent anyone from making changes outside of Terraform, for example using IAM policies in AWS.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and extended information. It is unfortunate we can't clearly identify the behaviour by reviewing the documentation. But I agree, the best practice is to avoid any modifications made outside of Terraform.